# Safari stuck on "Make Safari the default browser"

Tags: safari, mojave

Whenever I open Safari it prompts "Make Safari the default browser", but the dialog does not have any buttons and cannot be closed.

The only way out is to force-quit.

Any ideas?[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Try tweaking *Default browser* in system preferences -> General